# Bash wildcard not expanding

Tags: bash, wildcards, mkdir

I'm trying to make a directory for each file in a directory.

```
mkdir *
```

returns File exists. So I try

```
mkdir *.d
```

and it makes a directory called "*.d". How do I force the wildcard to expand?

Comment: Consider setting the _failglob_ option in your .bashrc file. This would have warned you when you did the `mkdir *.d`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A wildcard always expands to *existing* names.

Your command `mkdir *` fails because the names that `*` expands to already exists.

Your command `mkdir *.d` "fails" because the `*.d` does not match any existing names.  The pattern is therefore left unexpanded by default<sup>1</sup> and a directory called `*.d` is created.  You may remove this with `rmdir '*.d'`.

To create a directory for each *regular file* in the current directory, so that the new directories have the same name as the files, but with a `.d` suffix:

```
for name in ./*; do
    if [ -f "$name" ]; then
        # this is a regular file (or a symlink to one), create directory
        mkdir "$name.d"
    fi
done
```

or, for people that like "one-liners",

```
for n in ./*; do [ -f "$n" ] && mkdir "$n.d"; done
```

In `bash`, you could also do

```
names=( ./* )
mkdir "${names[@]/%/.d}"
```

but this makes no checks for whether the things that the glob expands to are regular files or something else.

The initial `./` in the commands above are to protect against filenames that contain an initial dash (`-`) in their filenames.  The dash and the characters following it would otherwise be interpreted as options to `mkdir`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Some shells have a `nullglob` shell option that causes non-matched shell wildcards to be expanded to an empty string.  In `bash` this is enabled using `shopt -s nullglob`.</sub>

Comment: It is bad idea to use `for name in ./*`. Instead I would go with `find . -depth 1 -and -type f -exec mkdir '{}.d' \;` which would work even if you have non-files in current directory.

Comment: @Hauleth In what way is it a bad idea? I'm testing each pathname before creating the directories, just like `find` would do. You `find` command would probably use `-maxdepth 1` rather than `-depth 1` (`-depth` does not take an argument) if `-maxdepth` is supported, and `-and` is not needed (and would make it non-portable). For a portable `find` variant: `find . -type f -exec mkdir {}.d ';' -o ! -name . -type d -prune`, but that would also create directories for hidden files.

Comment: @Hauleth ... (and it would still depend on whether the `find` implementation expands `{}.d` to the pathname concatenated with `.d`, which it isn't required to do).

Comment: To select only directories (in the bash solution) use `names=( ./*/ )`.

Comment: @Isaac Yes, but in this case we would ideally only want to select regular files. That's why I also mentioned that caveat.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `for foo in bar; do baz; done` solution I would propose:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0|xargs -0 -I file mkdir file.d`

Comment: If you'd like to avoid creating hidden directories (corresponding to hidden files), also use `! -name '.*'`.

Answer (score 2):

`*.d` expands to the files whose name end in `.d`.

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
files=(*)
mkdir -- $^files.d
```

Or with an anonymous function:

```
() { mkdir -- $^argv.d; } *
```

Or adding the suffix via the `e` glob qualifier:

```
mkdir -- *(e{REPLY+=.d})
```

Or the `:s` history modifier applied to globs (with `histsubstpattern` for `%` to mean *end*):

```
set -o histsubstpattern
mkdir -- *(:s/%/.d)
```

You may also want not to do that for files that are already directories or symlinks to directories, by adding a `^-/` glob qualifier:

```
files=(*(^-/))
mkdir -- $^files.d
```

<sup>(note that `zsh` doesn't have that misfeature of other Bourne-like shells where patterns that don't match are passed as-is, so `mkdir *.d` would not create a `*.d` directory if there was no file matching `*.d` in the current directory, it would abort the command with an error instead)</sup>